# Firebase Database Querying PHP anyoption to Multiple value search Like Mysql In

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I have **database table** with **userInfo** and i have a **field** to store **user tickets**.A user can have multiple tickets Say , *user1 tickets: {t1,t2,t3}*
*user2 tickets:{t1,t2}*.I want to search user with a particulat ticket (ex : `select * from users where tickets in(t1) in mysql`).Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps: SELECT * FROM users WHERE tickets LIKE '%t1%'

the % wildcard matches any number of characters.

Let me know if this worked for you.